# Generating a new object from an api array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I'm trying to do is take the array of objects that is returned to me from the API and create a new object and then add that object to the employees list.

I am getting the correct results from the API its just creating a new object from the results and attaching that object to the employeesList array.

```
var employeesList = [];

this.getEmployees = function () {
    $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&results=100&inc=name,location")
    .then(function(response) {
        employees = response.data.results;
        employees.map(employee => {
            return [
                employee.employeeName = employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last, 
                employee.employeeStreet = employee.location.street.number + ' ' + employee.location.street.name,
                employee.employeeCity = employee.location.city,
                employee.employeeState = employee.location.state,
                employee.employeeZipCode = employee.location.postcode,
            ];
        });
    });
    return employeesList;
};
```

The expected results are an array of employee objects however I am getting an empty array before I even return the employeesList.

**UPDATE** I have the initial problem working however it makes it difficult when I am trying to add or delete an employee.

```
this.addEmployee = function (employee) {
    var employeesList = this.getEmployees();
    employeesList.push(employee);
    var str = JSON.stringify(employeesList);
    localStorage.setItem("Employees", str);
};

this.removeEmployee = function (employee) {
    var employeesList = this.getEmployees();
    employeesList.splice(employeesList.indexOf(employee), 1);
    var str = JSON.stringify(employeesList);
    localStorage.setItem("Employees", str);
};
```

Comment: The `$http` service does not wait for the data to arrive from the server. It holds the function in the `.then` block and invokes that function later. Functions that depend on the `$http` service can never return data. They can only return promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needs to return the $http promise:

```
this.getEmployees = function () {
    var url = "https://randomuser.me/api";
    var params = {
      nat: "us",
      results: 100,
      inc: "name,location"
    };
    var config = { params: params };

    var promise = $http.get(url, config)
    var newPromise = promise.then(function(response) {
        var list = response.data.results;
        var newList = list.map(employee => ({
          employeeName: employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last, 
          employeeStreet: employee.location.street.number + ' ' + employee.location.street.name,
          employeeCity: employee.location.city,
          employeeState: employee.location.state,
          employeeZipCode: employee.location.postcode,
        }));
        return newList;
    });
    return newPromise;
};
```

Then the calling code needs to extract the data from the promise:

```
var promise = this.getEmployees();

promise.then(list => {
    console.log(list);
    this.employeeList = list;
});
```

Points to remember:

1. The `$http` service returns a promise
2. The `.then` method returns a *new* promise based on returned values
3. The `array.map` method returns a new array
4. Data needs to be extracted from promises

---

> UPDATE I have the initial problem working however it makes it difficult when I am trying to add or delete an employee.

The `$http` service does not wait for the data to arrive from the server. It holds the function in the `.then` block and invokes that function later. Functions that depend on the `$http` service can never return data. They can only return promises.

```
this.addEmployee = employee => {
    ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶e̶m̶p̶l̶o̶y̶e̶e̶s̶L̶i̶s̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶g̶e̶t̶E̶m̶p̶l̶o̶y̶e̶e̶s̶(̶)̶;̶
    var promise = this.getEmployees();

    promise.then(function(employeesList) {
        employeesList.push(employee);
        var str = JSON.stringify(employeesList);
        localStorage.setItem("Employees", str);
    });
};
```

Code that depends on data from the server must be placed in a `.then` block. That way the code executes after the data arrives from the server.

Comment: Is there anything I can do so that in my other methods inside my dataService I can work with the array more efficiently. I'll be adding an update to my post.

Comment: I added my further questions in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Following might give you expected list.

```
employees.map(employee => {
    employee.employeeName = employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last;
    employee.employeeStreet = employee.location.street.number + ' ' + employee.location.street.name;
    employee.employeeCity = employee.location.city;
    employee.employeeState = employee.location.state;
    employee.employeeZipCode = employee.location.postcode;

    return employee;
});
```

Comment: Its creating the employ object correctly but not adding it to the employeesList array.

Comment: You are mutating the original employee object, not creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The success handler of a promise does not have a return value.

This line creates a global variable called employees.

```
employees = response.data.results;
```

This line creates a new array that is not assigned to anything and falls straight to garbage collection.

```
employees.map(employee => { // your map function });
```

You map function takes each employee and creates an array so you are ending up with an array of arrays.

What you need to do is assign the correct mapping to employeesList in the success handler of the promise after it resolves.

```
this.getEmployees = function () {
  $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?nat=us&results=100&inc=name,location")
  .then(function(response) {
    employeesList = response.data.results.map(employee => ({
      employeeName: employee.name.first + ' ' + employee.name.last, 
      employee.employeeStreet: employee.location.street.number + ' ' + employee.location.street.name,
      employeeCity: employee.location.city,
      employeeState: employee.location.state,
      employeeZipCode: employee.location.postcode
    }));
  });
};
```